# Weird labeling in C# TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have an issue using C#'s TreeView.

- If I put a text on a node, like "Hello World", the tree shows me the correct label
- If I put a text on a node, like "1-Hello World" or "1Hello World", is showed ok, too.

But if I put a text using someNumber(s)[space]someWord like "1 Hello World" or "1323 Hello World", in the tree view is showed like "HelloWorld 1" or "Hello World 1323".

[Image 1, command Line (the toolTip is over "node.Text")](http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_7752478commandline.png)

[Image2, TreeView:](http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_7752502treeview.png)

(sorry, I'm a newbie, can't post pics)

I've tried even sending the commandline from de immediate window, like node.Text="123 Hello World" and the node still shows me "Hello World 123".

I'm using VS2010 in W7.

Any idea/s?
i'm driving nuts...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: by the way, i've tried changing the regional and language settings from w7's control panel, with no best results.

Comment: Please add an appropriate tag like `winforms`, 'wpf`, `silverlight`, `webforms` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your FlowDirection set to RightToLeft?
Try setting it to LeftToRight.

Comment: Thanks. I can't find "FlowDirection" in this TreeView. (My app is win32, maybe that's why? Checking "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.flowdirection.aspx#Y0")

Comment: Sorry I thought you were using wpf. In winforms try setting the RightToLeft property to No

Comment: Ok, tried. Property modification works, but the text of the node is still wrong: http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_7754907errtree.png

Comment: I've programed a class inherited from TreeView. I've configured the property "RightToLeft" to "No" in this class. it started to work fine. [http://s3.subirimagenes.com:81/imagen/previo/thump_7757974sin-ttulo.png] it's a mystery...  i'm using my class almost "transparent", except by this property. Now i'm happy. Thanks, Alex. i've a beer with your name on it.